# Font-face not working with Sass

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I like to think I know what I'm doing when it comes to font-face and Sass, but not this time it seems.

I'm trying to use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Theano-Didot on **http://tjob.be/**. I used the fontsquirrel generator from that ttf as usual and the files seem fine.

So why isn't it showing the correct font?

The heading for instance, where it says "Tjobbe Andrews is a freelance photographer and web designer" should be in this font, not Georgia.

I'm getting the same cross-browser, mobile and desktop.

Totally stumped.

Relevant CSS:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: "theano_didotregular";
  src: url("theanodidot-regular-webfont.eot");
  src: url("theanodidot-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
        url("theanodidot-regular-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
        url("theanodidot-regular-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("theanodidot-regular-webfont.svg#theano_didotregular") format("svg");
}
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<h2>Tjobbe Andrews is a freelance photographer and web designer</h2>
```

Comment: You need to copy your relevant code to the question.  When this problem is solved, or your site is gone, this question will have no value any longer.

Comment: I don't see a @font-face declaration in your css - it looks like you are using WOFF.  However, I'm wondering if your font name matches the font name of your font? It *does* look like your font file is where it needs to be.

Comment: Based on my fiddling with things, I suspect the font files are corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "theano_didotregular";
    src: url("<correctpathofthefile>/theanodidot-regular-webfont.eot");
    src: url("<correctpathofthefile>/theanodidot-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
    url("<correctpathofthefile>/theanodidot-regular-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
    url("<correctpathofthefile>/theanodidot-regular-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("<correctpathofthefile>/theanodidot-regular-webfont.svg#theano_didotregular") format("svg");
}

h2 {
    font-family: "theano_didotregular";
}
```

It should works ;)

Comment: This is not sass